# Commutative Monoid - matrix set

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $M$={$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
c & a & b \\ 
b & c & a
\end{bmatrix}|a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}, a+b+c=0$}. The matrices in $M$ are a special kind of Toeplitz matrices (circulant). It is easy to show that $M$ is closed under the regular operation "$\cdot$" of multiplication. Associativity and commutativity follow in the same manner. When trying to prove that $(M,\cdot)$ is a commutative monoid, a problem arose. So we are searching for an element $I\in M$ such that $AI=IA=A,\forall A\in M$. Denoting $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1  & c_1 \\ 
c_1 & a_1 & b_1\\ 
b_1 & c_1 & a_1
\end{bmatrix}$ and B=$\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & z\\ 
z & x & y\\ 
y & z & x
\end{bmatrix}$, after calculations I obtained the following system: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(a_1-b_1)x-(a_1+2b_1)y=a_1  \\ 
(2a_1+b_1)x+(a_1-b_1)y=a_1+b_1 
\end{matrix}\right.\;,$$ where $a_1,b_1$are real numbers (varying) and $x, y$ are the unknowns (we need to find $x,y$ such that this solution(s) work for all $a,b$). It seems that $x=\frac{2}{3}, y=\frac{-1}{3}$  are good and then, from $x+y+z=0$ we get $z=\frac{-1}{3}$. My question is: how can we prove that this is the only good solution (so that $$I=-\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3}  &\frac{1}{3} \\ 
 \frac{1}{3}& \frac{2}{3} &\frac{1}{3} \\ 
\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3}  & \frac{2}{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I improved the math formatting. Equations are displayed (instead of inline) if you enclose them in double dollar signs -- with things like systems of equations, that makes for much greater readability. Note also that you don't need all those braces for single-digit fractions like `\frac13`. I didn't change the $I$ matrix at the end, but I'm pretty sure you wanted some minus signs in there, and not to have the factor $\frac13$ both outside and inside.

Comment: @joriki Thank you very much for the advices! It was a mistake at the matrix $I$.

Comment: I think it's still not right; now the minus sign applies to all entries, whereas $x$ is supposed to be $2/3$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from the system of equations that you derived. Since the system must be satisfied for arbitrary $a_1$, $b_1$, the coefficients of $a_1$ and $b_1$ must vanish separately. (Equivalently, the equations you get when substituting $a_1=1$, $b_1=0$ and when substituting $a_1=0$, $b_1=1$ must be satisfied.) This gives a system of equations which can easily be shown to have only that one solution.